# Como remover/desinstalar toda a camada LAMP?

Tags: servidor, lamp

Tenho um servidor web no qual gostaria de remover toda a camada LAMP de forma a proceder à reinstalação de raiz de todos os pacotes, como posso realizar esta operação?

Comment: Qual sistema você está usando?

Comment: @AndréRibeiro Linux Mint 17 Quiana

Comment: Foi tudo instalado via apt?

Comment: @AndréRibeiro Sim, toda e qualquer instalação foi realizada via `apt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para remover somente os principais pacotes você pode usar:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server apache2 php5
```

Para remover estes pacotes e todos os outros relacionados:

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils apache2.2-common libapache2-mod-php5 libapr1 libaprutil1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libmysqlclient15off libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl libpq5 mysql-client-5.0 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.0 php5-common php5-mysql
```

- Para remover as configurações do apache remova o diretório `/etc/apache2`
- MySQL usa o arquivo de configuração `/etc/my.cnf`
- O PHP.ini costuma ficar em `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`. Para saber a localização exata do arquivo você pode usar a função `phpinfo()`.

[Fonte](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50101/how-do-i-remove-the-lamp-stack-so-i-can-start-over)

Comment: O MySQL pode usar uma de [muitas localizações possíveis](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html), tudo dependendo de um universo de variantes no sistema ou versão do MySQL, apesar que o uso dos ficheiros `my.cnf` é realizado em cascata. No meu caso estava em `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.